# After hosting to server symfony2 gives 500 internal server error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

My website is created using symfony2. The site is working fine on my local machine but after hosting it, the homepage `css` files are not loading. This is how I have written the code:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/public/shop/shopHome.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" >
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/public/introPopups.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" >
    {{ user_apply.stylesheets() }}
{% endblock %}
```

And the error is

```
http://example.com/project/web/assets/css/public/shop/shopHome.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: And what do the hosting server logs say?

Comment: Haven't checked server logs, do I need to check?

Comment: minor formatting/grammar improvements

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed to execute on production

`php app/console assets:install web --symlink`

Comment: Okay I just want to ask am I missing anything during hosting? I just put all the files from my local machine to server , set up database and I am using http://host/projectname/web/app_dev.php/

Comment: then check is %root of example.com%/project/web/assets/css/public/shop/shopHome.css file exists, uploaded in camelCase (better use all lowercase) and check file permissions (does user of web server have read rights)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed all the dependencies in composer.json
Try running

`composer install`

inside your main app repo where composer.json is present.

If composer not installed, try

[Installing Composer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/composer.html)

If this doesn't work, please see & share app logs in:

`tail -f app/logs/prod.log`